# How to define a math bold font in Plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, bold, plain-tex

Consider the following code:

```
\font\rm=ecrm1000\rm
\font\bf=ecbx1000

R{\bf R} $R{\bf R}$

\bye
```

The result I get is R**R** *R**R*.
However I was expecting R**R** *R***R**

Why the second R in the math formula not rendered in bold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The selecting of text font has no effect in math typesetting. You defined `\bf` as selecting text font only, you cannot expect anything in math.

The plain TeX original `\bf` macro does two actions in parallel. See plain.tex file:

```
\def\bf {\fam\bffam \tenbf}
```

First, it selects text font `\tenbf` and second, it selects *math alphabet* collected in the `\bffam` math family by `\fam\bffam`.

You can declare:

```
\font\tenbf=ecbx1000
```

and keep the plain TeX macro `\bf` unchanged. Now, `\bf` will select your font in text mode and it keeps the selecting of math alphabet `\fam\bffam` in math mode.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do like that, but use the already existing infrastructure

```
\font\tenrm=ecrm1000
\font\sevenrm=ecrm0700
\font\fiverm=ecrm0500
\font\tenbf=ecbx1000
\font\sevenbf=ecbx0700
\font\fivebf=ecbx0500
\rm

R{\bf R} $R{\bf R}$
\bye
```

[image]